# How to find the site column details using a Web service?

Tags: 2007, web-services, site-column

I have a site column of type "Choice" with 8 choices and associated with a list, is there a way to get those details (list of choices) using a web service ?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. Take a look at the GetList operation in the Lists Web Service. And to make it even easier, look at http://spservices.codeplex.com if you want to do this client side.